# Refactor a method

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

VS Performance profiler has identified the following method as "hot". I'm sure sure of a good way to refactor it to make it less hot so just wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJurisdictions()
    {
        using (var context = new DAL.ObservationEntities())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> JurisdictionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var items = (from j in context.Jurisdictions orderby j.Name select j).ToList();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                JurisdictionsList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Name.ToString(), Value = item.GUID.ToString() });
            }
            return JurisdictionsList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: IIRC a "hot" method doesn't necessarily mean the method itself is problematic.  It can just mean that the method is *called* a lot.  Without a lot more context around how this method is used, I don't think SO will be able to provide much help.

Comment: the obvious thing is not to reread from the database every time but to cache the data. But 'hot' means its called a lot, not that its slow, remember some combination of code always takes all the time.

Comment: You are loading the entire table at once .. this can be an issue if your table is huge , so think of adding pagination (batch processing) . And your are only using two fields(name and guid) from the table so you can only select those two .

Comment: How many items are in `Jurisdictions`?

Answer (score 2):

You are looping the data twice and you are pulling more data from the database than you really need.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJurisdictions()
{
    using (var context = new DAL.ObservationEntities())
    {
        var query = from j in context.Jurisdictions 
                    orderby j.Name
                    select new SelectListItem {
                        Text = item.Name,
                        Value = item.GUID.ToString(),
                    };
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Your original code was basically doing `SELECT * FROM Jurisdictions ORDER BY Name` and then looping the data twice.

Comment: My only concern is that the GUID.ToString() here might make the IQueryable mad if the database can't call that method. That's why I included AsEnumerable() in mine but again, I'm not positive it's required

Comment: That is the correct way to convert GUID to string with EF ... but as you pointed out in your answer you could toss in a `.AsEnumerable()` for good measure (just make sure to select only the fields you want returned first).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is that you have no `where` clause in here so you're selecting the entire table. If the table is tiny, that's fine, otherwise you'll probably want that.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJurisdictions()
{
    using (var context = new DAL.ObservationEntities())
    {
        var items = (from j in context.Jurisdictions orderby j.Name select new { j.Name, j.GUID })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(j => new SelectListItem { Text = j.Name, Value = j.GUID.ToString() })
                    .ToList();

        return items;
    }
}
```

You might not need the `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: instead of `select j` I'd suggest `select new {j.Name, j.GUID}`... `select j` is pretty much the same as `select *`

Comment: @MatthewWhited I agree.. will change

Comment: You've now succeeded in not making your solution *worse* than the OP's, but haven't succeeded in making it *better*.

Comment: It is better as it's not looping the data twice.

Comment: That's not going to be a *significant* difference.  If it was a problem before, it's a problem now, and if it's not a problem now, it wasn't a problem before.

Comment: @JoePhillips It's *stylistically* better.  The OP didn't ask to make their code look prettier.  They asked how to make the method less hot.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: Seeing that OPs version was pulling more data and dealing with it twice per call this will improve performance.  If he is having an issue at the calling points then that's a different question.

Comment: @Servy How exactly could it be done without changing the output? A refactor means the output should remain the same. There's not much else to improve that I can see

Comment: @JoePhillips If it can't be done then say it can't be done, don't provide an answer that doesn't answer the question and claim that it actually answers the question.

Comment: He wants you to say something about caching the data... but that shouldn't be done from this point.  if you are going to add caching it should be futher up the call from the DB query.  (in my opinion)

Comment: We don't even know if we're dealing with a database at this point. We just know it's data. Without a trace, caching may provide the smallest gain of anything

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a couple of different things.

First up, this function's actually doing three things:

1. it's getting the data from DAL
2. it's creating a list of SelectedListItem
3. it's transforming the data in step #1 and putting it into the
   list in step #2.

Why does this matter?

Well, let's say you write a function later on that could really use that Jurisdiction data.  You can't really re-use your current function, because it's not returning Jurisdiction data - it's returning GUI elements for your combo box.

Or lets say you want to cache the data.  Do you want to cache the GUI elements... or the return from the LINQ statement?  Other elements of your program might want different pieces of that jurisdiction data, not just the Name/GUID.

Next up - look at what your current function is returning: IEnumerable.  That implies that it's not actually a fully fleshed-out list.  I mean, I should be able to write code like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> idList = GetIDEnumerable();
int firstID = idList.FirstOrDefault();
```

... and not have it actually traverse through the entire set of data.  That GetIDEnumerable() might be containing 10 million rows... but if I do it right, the process doesn't have to touch anything but the first row!  But the minute you declare lists and populate them, you're having to traverse through all the records.  (It might not matter now, but imagine you later need to write a function to get the first Jurisdiction that meets a certain criteria - you can't do that quickly right now, because your function loops through all the records.)

So, here's how I'd change it:

First, create your IEnumerable GetJurisdictionEnumerable() function, where all it does is return that LINQ statement, like:

```
IEnumerable<???> GetJursidctionEnumerableFromDB()
{
    using (var context = new DAL.ObservationEntities())
        return (from j in context.Jurisdictions orderby j.Name select j);
    }
}
```

Next up, write a function that gathers a list of Jurisdiction items, either from cache or from a fresh result.

```
IEnumerable<???> GetJurisdictionEnumerable()
{
    if (cached data is still good)
        return a cached List<???> object.
    // we don't want the cache to be IEnumerable - we want to actually store the contents,
    // not just a way of enumerating through the contents
    cached List<???> = GetJurisdictionEnumerableFromDB().ToList();
    return cached List<???>
}
```

After that, a function that transforms a Jurisdiction element into your GUI item:

```
SelectedListItem TransformJurisdictionIntoComboElement(??? jurisRecord)
{
    return new SelectedListItem()
    {
        Text = jurisRecord.Name.ToString(),
        Value = jurisRecord.GUID.ToString()
    }
}
```

Finally, when you want to populate the combo box

```
// ... code to populate combo box
IEnumerable<???> jurisData = GetJurisdictionEnumerable();
foreach(??? j in jurisData)
    combobox.Add(TransformJurisdictionIntoComboElement(j));
```

It's 3 functions instead of 1 (well, it'd only be 2 without caching), but it doesn't violate SRP.  And it'll be a lot more flexible if your code changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one cheap optimisation: your `items` object does not need to be turned into a `List` as it can be iterated over as a plain `IEnumerable`.

Updated code:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJurisdictions()
{
    using (var context = new DAL.ObservationEntities())
    {
        List<SelectListItem> JurisdictionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var items = (from j in context.Jurisdictions orderby j.Name select j); // Removed toList()
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            JurisdictionsList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Name.ToString(), Value = item.GUID.ToString() });
        }
        return JurisdictionsList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select just Jurisdictions names instead of the entire object.

It's most likely however that the database is taking a while to return the information. You could look at caching the results instead of going to the database whenever you need this dropdown. Or you could look at database optimizations to get this data returned quicker.

Oh, You could look at compiled linq queries as well. Building the query for the first time can take a lot of time.

Comment: Regarding specific database optimizations, consider checking whether Jurisdictions has an index on Name.